# Identification of arm like beam

Tags: technic, part-identification

Any part number information about this technic beam?

[image]

Comment: I just realized this is the piece used for legs in AT-AT walker 8129.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parts you are looking for are [Technic Rotation Joint Disk with Pin Hole and 3L Liftarm Thick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=44224) and [Technic Rotation Joint Disk with Pin and 3L Liftarm Thick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=44225).

Comment: Do you know if they make sense when they are not in pairs?

Comment: Can you expand on "make sense"? I have seen one half used by itself in both MOCs and official sets such as http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=6857-1 mostly as fork/hub connection for motorcycles.

Comment: While they go nicely together, they are not pre-assembled, so they are to be considered as individual parts which can be used independently. I didn't know it even happened in an official LEGO set, though - nice catch

Comment: I think I just meant if they are functional as individual parts, like you can get some other kind of rotation. I found them as 4 pairs in a flee market so I don't really know where they came from.